# Copy text to clipboard from SVG with line breaks

Tags: javascript, svg, text, clipboard, line-breaks

Line breaks in SVG are represented using `tspan` elements with `dy` attributes.  Like this:

```html
  <text>
    <tspan x="10">line 1</tspan> 
    <tspan x="10" dy="15">line 2</tspan> 
  </text>
```

This displays on two lines as expected.  The problem is when copying the resulting text to the clipboard there is no line break (tested in Chrome and Firefox).  Is there a way to encode a CR-LF onto the line ends?

Not having line breaks in the clipboard makes it problematic to present code samples in an SVG application, for example, since users can't copy and paste the code into their editors.

Here is a demo in JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/78b9g8je/

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? [Repology's version badges](https://repology.org/badge/vertical-allrepos/pdfarranger.svg?columns=4&exclude_unsupported=1) are another application where linebreaks would make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no solution for this problem because `<tspan>` elements only "mimic" line-breaks by x/y offsets. In fact every svg text element is just a line of text. It can't work until we see a revised svg text concept adding proper multi-line support.